# ProGuard + Spring Boot + Maven Plugin

Tags: maven, spring-boot, proguard

Guys, I'm trying to obfuscate a .jar application using the proguard-maven-plugin.
When I try to perform the obfuscate process, I get error messages stating that there are unexpected classes.

I'm using the Spring Boot 1.4.1.RELEASE and Proguard Maven Plugin 2.0.13.

This is my **proguard.conf**

```
-injars /workspace/base/target/test-1.0.0.jar

-libraryjars /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_101.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar

-dontshrink
-dontoptimize
-dontobfuscate
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-keepattributes Exceptions,InnerClasses,Signature,Deprecated,SourceFile,LineNumberTable,LocalVariable*Table,*Annotation*,Synthetic,EnclosingMethod

-adaptresourcefilenames **.properties
-adaptresourcefilecontents **.properties,META-INF/MANIFEST.MF

-dontpreverify
-verbose


-keepclasseswithmembers public class * {
    public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
}

-keepclassmembers enum  * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class * extends java.beans.BeanInfo

-keep class * {
    void set*(***);
    void set*(int,***);
    boolean is*();
    boolean is*(int);
    *** get*();
    *** get*(int);
}

-assumenosideeffects public class java.lang.System {
    public static long currentTimeMillis();
    static java.lang.Class getCallerClass();
    public static int identityHashCode(java.lang.Object);
    public static java.lang.SecurityManager getSecurityManager();
    public static java.util.Properties getProperties();
    public static java.lang.String getProperty(java.lang.String);
    public static java.lang.String getenv(java.lang.String);
    public static java.lang.String mapLibraryName(java.lang.String);
    public static java.lang.String getProperty(java.lang.String,java.lang.String);
}
```

The **pom.xml** file. I am only informing the configuration by the plugin.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.github.wvengen</groupId>
    <artifactId>proguard-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.13</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>proguard</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <obfuscate>false</obfuscate>
        <outFilter>**/BOOT-INF/classes/ **.class</outFilter>

        <proguardInclude>${basedir}/proguard.conf</proguardInclude>
        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>

        <injar>${project.build.finalName}.jar</injar>
        <outjar>${project.build.finalName}-min.jar</outjar>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

However, during the execution process I get the following return for all classes in my application.

```
Warning: class [BOOT-INF/classes/br/com/base/BaseApplication.class] unexpectedly contains class [br.com.base.BaseApplication]
Warning: class [BOOT-INF/classes/br/com/base/controller/CaixaController.class] unexpectedly contains class [br.com.base.controller.CaixaController]
[...]
```

And the final output of ProGuard. PS: *All classes are in the `BOOT-INF/classes` directory*

```
Warning: there were 97 classes in incorrectly named files.
You should make sure all file names correspond to their class names.
The directory hierarchies must correspond to the package hierarchies.
     (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unexpectedclass)
If you don't mind the mentioned classes not being written out,
you could try your luck using the '-ignorewarnings' option.
Please correct the above warnings first.
```

Can anyone imagine any alternatives I can try?
Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to fix this, I made sure to change the order of the plugins in the pom. The proguard plugin should go first, followed by the spring boot plugin.

Additionally, make sure you have the `<goal>repackage</goal>` specified in the spring boot configuration. With the correct order and the repackage goal specified, the proguard obfuscation/optimization/whatever you have configured will take place and produce a jar. Then the spring boot plugin will repackage that jar as an executable and everything should work.

My plugin configuration from pom.xml:

```
<project ...>
....
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.github.wvengen</groupId>
    <artifactId>proguard-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>proguard</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <proguardInclude>${basedir}/proguard.conf</proguardInclude>
        <libs>
            <lib>${java.home}/lib/rt.jar</lib>
            <lib>${java.home}/lib/jce.jar</lib>
        </libs>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>repackage</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <start-class>org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher</start-class>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
...
```

Comment: How do you include additional modules, when your spring boot app is multimodule?